# Allow users add javascripts on their subdomains

Tags: security, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, xss

I'm using CakePHP 2.6. I want to create a website like blogger(blogspot) where every registered user has its subdomain and can add its articles add javascript codes.

Is is safe to allow registered users to add javascripts on their subdomains?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Is is safe to allow registered users to add javascripts on their
>   subdomains?

If done *right* yes. Search for JSONP, CSRF, XSS, CORS, and [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

I'm clearly not going to explain all of this in an answer, it is far to much for this place here.

Answer (score 0):

Allowing arbitrary JavaScript, Flash and other active content (such as iframes etc...) from untrusted sources carries a security risk. JavaScript and other active content can be used for malicious purposes through the use of Cross-Site Scripting (XSS).

Allowing JavaScript from untrusted sources has caused issues in the past (one of the most famous examples of this was the [MySpace XSS worm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samy_%28computer_worm%29)).

For an overview on XSS I suggest you take a look at the [following resource](http://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/cross-site-scripting/) from Acunetix.